# VB6 Error 371 The specified object can't be used as an owner

Tags: vb6

First of all forgive me if you think I'm just being lazy about asking here for information about this VB6 error, without having researched it properly, because I'm not (perhaps sometimes), and I have.

A project that was dispatched to a client, immediately gives this error when run - BUT the application runs fine here.

Apparently, this error ONLY occurs when an MDI child attempts to show a form, passing itself as its owner.

Well, this is all fine and dandy, but OUR application does NOT use MDI forms. At All. This is the line of code which generates the error:

```
   Me.Show vbModal, Screen.ActiveForm
```

As I've said, the application does not use any MDI forms, so I'm flummoxed as to why this error is being reported.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding some logging to check what `Screen.ActiveForm` is when the error occurs. Write these expressions to a text file: `(Screen.ActiveForm Is Nothing)`, and on a separate code line in case an error occurs `Screen.ActiveForm.Name`

Comment: Could Screen.ActiveForm not be what you think it is? Is it running on a terminal session of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

The ActiveForm property of the Screen object has a type of an abstract class ("Form").

The error message is telling you that the Show method will require a reference to an instance of a concrete class derived from Form.  This is just as documented:

> If you plan to pass Screen.ActiveForm or MDIForm.ActiveForm to a procedure, you must declare the argument in that procedure with the generic type (As Form) rather than a specific form type (As MyForm) even if **ActiveForm** always refers to the same type of form.

So the workaround would be to declare a variable of the desired Form-based type, set it to Screen.ActiveForm, and then use that object reference in your Show call.

Here we have:

```
Option Explicit
'
'Form1 code
'

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Load Form2 'This is not the class Form2, but the predeclared instance named Form2.
End Sub
```

And:

```
Option Explicit
'
'Form2 code
'

Private Sub Form_Load()
    'Use a Timer to defer the Show until after we've returned control to Form1:
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    Dim Owner As Form1 'This is the class Form1, not the predeclared instance named Form1.

    Timer1.Enabled = True
    Set Owner = Screen.ActiveForm
    Show vbModal, Owner
End Sub
```

Seems to work just as expected and as documented, though I have no idea why anyone would ever need to do this.

Why not just call Show on Form2 back in Form1's code in the first place?

Comment: @Bob77.Thx.The complication with my situation is that I dont know what form is the active form-ie. I can't say it's FormX/Y.The screen thats attempted to be shown is activated on  a Timer-the event checks to see if there are any network related issues and if so displays the form informing the user of the problem & asking if they wish to reconnect.This a mature app & it is the first time we've seen this error(371)reported which seemingly only occurs when used with MDIChild forms-which we don't use.And,being a production application,we cant debug it on the client's system to see what's wrong